# I did (Something) as much as I would in (X amount of time)

Tags: grammar

In english there is a common expression that is "I did (something) as much as I would in (A period of time)". Generally in this pattern the period of time is a large period of time - and the expression is used to express a sense of being impressed. 
I'm trying to figure out if Chinese has an equivalent expression - or a similar way of expressing the meaning.

For example, how would I say "I laughed more today than I usually would in a week" 
Could I say:
"今天我笑得比正常的一个礼拜多“

Answer (score 3):

You own answer is almost correct. I'd add one character to make sound more natural:
今天我笑得比正常的一个礼拜**还**多

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

> 我今天笑得比平时一个礼拜还多

I think `平时` is more proper than `正常`, `平时` means `normal times` while `正常` simply means `normal`, in this situation, `平时` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

A more natural way may be: “我今天**一天**笑的比一个礼拜的还多“. "一天" is added after "今天",  to compare with “一个礼拜", so it will be empathized. Similar to "as much as" in original sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You might not use English sentence construction in Chinese.

In Cantonese, I would say

平時成個禮拜笑，笑得都冇今日咁多。

Using more format construction

平日一周都有笑，然而今日笑得特別多。